# Best way to switch pipe filters?

Tags: angular, pipe

I am writing a basic app in Angular 2+ but I want to know the best way to switch the pipe filter, I tried using `boolean? "filter1" : "filter2"` but it kept giving me errors about 'toUpperCase', so this is what I came up with, and while it is functional it is repeating code which id like to avoid and find the most effective way to do this;

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Serves</th>
    <th>Remarks</th>
  </tr>
  <ng-container *ngIf="filterText">
    <tr *ngFor="let recipe of recipes | searchByString: filterText">
      <td>{{ recipe.ID }}</td>
      <td>{{ recipe.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ recipe.serves }}</td>
      <td>{{ recipe.remarks }}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container *ngIf="!filterText">
    <tr *ngFor="let recipe of recipes | OrderBy : (filter? ['-name'] : ['+name'])">
      <td>{{ recipe.ID }}</td>
      <td>{{ recipe.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ recipe.serves }}</td>
      <td>{{ recipe.remarks }}</td>
    </tr>
  </ng-container>
  </table>

Sort recipe by name<input type="checkbox"  [(ngModel)]="filter">
<p></p>
Filter String: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filterText"
                      class="form-control" placeholder="Search By Category" />
```

As you can see above im repeating code, although it works It goes against standard practice I believe? either way id rather learn how to do it properly while I am still new to this.

Comment: The very first example on the official website does this: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#parameterizing-a-pipe. Make the pipe a component variable, make a method that changes the variable to toggle the pipe.

Comment: @Z.Bagley that is using a boolean? "filter1" : "filter2" and as I described that doesnt work because im using 2 different methods to filter

Comment: It's also using a string for the DatePipe

Comment: The method is different though, searchByString and OrderBy arent interchangable

Comment: My comment technically does not really describe the answer to your question. Nevertheless, I'll express my suggestion. IMO, it's better to keep as much logic outside of the template code as possible. So, instead of `recipes`, I'd expose a `sortedRecipes` property from your `component.ts`. I only use pipes for _formatting_ the output, instead of manipulating the actual data. This is because our `{{ xxx }}` expressions are evaluated on every change detection (which are SUPER frequent unless you use OnPush strategy)... Just my two cents.

Comment: @Cacoon by the way, is your question about the Angular.js  or Angular 2/4 ?

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko the 'angular' tag delagates angualr2+, angularJS would be the tag for just original angularjs